# for loop with if condition

Tags: php, html, twig

I have different category with value and I want to show Category Name Only one time. I tried this way but it's show me category name multiple time :-

```
<th>Properties</th>
<td>
    {% for sec in entity.appliedFeatures %}
        {{ sec.featuresCategory }} :-
        {{ sec.name }}
    % endfor %}
</td>
```

And result :-

```
Properties  Style :- japanese || Style :- russian || Style :- american || Outdoor Features :- music system in park || Outdoor Features :- Basketball Court || Special Rooms :- Camere Special ||
```

These are categories :-  **Style, Outdoor Features, Special Rooms**

I want to show these categories only one time. I had tried an if condition with loop.index but then it shows only one category name.

I want result result like this :-

```
Properties  Style :- japanese, russian, american || Outdoor Features :- music system in park,Basketball Court || Special Rooms :- Camere Special ||
```

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this will work?

```
{% set previous = false %}
{% for sec in entity.appliedFeatures %}
    {% if not previous or previous.featuresCategory != sec.featuresCategory %}
        {{ sec.featuresCategory }} :-
    {% endif %}
    {{ sec.name }}
    {% set previous = sec %}
{% endfor %}
```

There's no built in method in Twig to get the previous loop item, so, this is probably the best you can do without altering your data structure before you pass it to Twig to render the template.

It may need some tweaking to make it look exactly how you want.

Comment: Thanks for answer But  !previous  show Unexpected character "!"  ?

Comment: Oops! I've updated my answer, see if this works now :), it's been a while since I've used Twig!

Comment: Hmm, edited it some more after looking up more of the Twig syntax, hopefully this is right now!

Comment: Your first answer is right. Only First category name is not coming :- {% set previous = false %}
{% for sec in entity.appliedFeatures %}
    {% if previous and previous.featuresCategory != sec.featuresCategory %}
  {{ sec.featuresCategory }} :-
    {% endif %}
    {{ sec.name }}
    {% set previous = sec %}
 </br>
{% endfor %}    and reuslt is :- japanese 
russian 
american
Outdoor Features :- music system in park 
Basketball Court 
Special Rooms :- Camere Special  in result first category Style is not coming. Can you see this ?

Comment: Make sure it's `if not previous` then `or` the other condition. If previous is false, it has to print out (this is the first iteration of the loop).

Comment: Or in other words, from what you copied and pasted in your comment, this: `{% if not previous or previous.featuresCategory != sec.featuresCategory %}`.